# How can I run an SQL statement in Powerbuilder and have the results show up in Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, powerbuilder

Is it possible to have a SQL statement in powerbuilder, but instead of the results displaying in a datawindow, have it displayed in Excel?  I'm not able to find anything on this topic, and I'm relatively new to powerbuilder and programming.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not connect Excel to the data source directly?

Comment: I need it to be a program that a user can run...it's a group of programs already.

Answer (score 1):

Use a nonvisual datastore class instead of a datawindow control.

Retrieve the data into the datastore class;
Use SaveAs() to save the data as an Excel file into the filesystem;
Use Run( "..path to Excel.exe" "XLSX file you just created", maximized!) to launch Excel and load the file;

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the OLE functions in powerbuilder. Be aware though that you will create a dependency on third party software. If ms changes something in excel and breaks your object in PB, good luck fixing that.